# Css select all but first tr doesn't work

Tags: html, css

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/80mek2sL/1/

I want to select all but the first `tr` and apply:

```
border-top: 1px grey solid;
```

Then I want to select all first `td`'s but not the first `td` of the first `tr` (= ignore first `tr`) and apply

```
border-right: 1px grey dotted;
```

(I totally dont care about compatibility with prehistorical Web browsers, I just want it to work on nowadays Web browsers)
What I dont get (that's why I'm lost actually) is that immediate selector `table > tr` doesn't select `tr` (otherwise I would have solved my problem)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selector is working. The problem is that `tr`'s don't have a border. You need to apply it the `td` within...

```
#cheatsheet tr:not(:first-child) td {
    border-top:1px grey solid;
    background-color: #EF0;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80mek2sL/2/)

```css
#cheatsheet td {
    margin:2px;
    padding:2px
}
#cheatsheet tr td:first-child {
    padding-left:10%;
    width:30%;
}
#cheatsheet thead {
    background-color: #EFE;
}
#cheatsheet h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
table#cheatsheet {
    border:1px black solid;
    margin:2px; padding:2px;
    border-right:1px grey solid;
    width:100%;
}
#cheatsheet tr:not(:first-child) td {
    border-top:1px grey solid;
    background-color: #EF0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Vim</h1>

<table id="cheatsheet">
    <thead><tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h3>aa</h3></td>
    </tr></thead>
    <tr>
        <td><code class="prettyprint lang-sh">:split</code></td>
        <td style="width:auto">bb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><code class="prettyprint lang-sh">:vsplit</code></td>
        <td style="width:auto">split vertical</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On another note, the reason `table > tr` doesn't work is because `tr`'s are not an immediate descendant of `table` in the rendered HTML. If you use your browsers element inspector you will see that `thead` and `tbody` elements are automatically inserted for you

---

EDIT
After the comment below all you need to do is this...

```
#cheatsheet tbody td {
    border-top:1px grey solid;
    background-color: #EF0;
}
```

ie. target the `td` within `tbody` only,

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80mek2sL/8/)

Comment: Thank you very much, it's almost what I'm looking for, but there shoud be a grey line on the top of the second row too.

Answer (score 0):

check fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/80mek2sL/6/

`nth-child(n+2)` selector helps to select any number of child. in following example I am selecting row from ahead of second child.

```
#cheatsheet tr:nth-child(n+2) td {
    border-top:1px grey solid;
    background-color: #EF0;
}
```

You can also play aorund `(n + *)` and check the result to better understand the `nth-child` selector

> note: you can not put border property to `<tr>` so you will need to
>   assign it to `<td>`

**HTML**

```
<table id="cheatsheet">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <h3>aa</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td><code class="prettyprint lang-sh">:split</code>
        </td>
        <td style="width:auto">bb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><code class="prettyprint lang-sh">:vsplit</code>
        </td>
        <td style="width:auto">split vertical</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><code class="prettyprint lang-sh">:vsplit</code>
        </td>
        <td style="width:auto">split vertical</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><code class="prettyprint lang-sh">:vsplit</code>
        </td>
        <td style="width:auto">split vertical</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#cheatsheet td {
    margin:2px;
    padding:2px
}
#cheatsheet tr td:first-child {
    padding-left:10%;
    width:30%;
}
#cheatsheet thead {
    background-color: #EFE;
}
#cheatsheet h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
table#cheatsheet {
    border:1px black solid;
    margin:2px;
    padding:2px;
    border-right:1px grey solid;
    width:100%;
}
#cheatsheet tr:nth-child(n+2) td {
    border-top:1px grey solid;
    background-color: #EF0;
}
```